# Cannot convert GeoJSON file to topo

Tags: topojson

I have a GeoJSON file that represents the local government areas for NSW (state in Australia). It looks something like this:-

```
{
"LocalGovernmentArea" : {
    "type" : "FeatureCollection",
    "features" : [
        {
            "type" : "Feature",
            "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Polygon",
                "coordinates" : [
                    [
                        // Lots of coordinates
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "properties" : {
                "rid" : 63,
                "startdate" : "20160115133054",
                "enddate" : "30000101000000",
                "lastupdate" : "20160115133106.993000",
                "msoid" : 74,
                "centroidid" : null,
                "shapeuuid" : "70e041ba-bd11-30c2-b86f-8b89eb516afa",
                "changetype" : "M",
                "processstate" : null,
                "urbanity" : "U",
                "Shape__Length" : 622956.5638272235,
                "Shape__Area" : 8579520431.758272,
                "cadid" : 108012460,
                "createdate" : "20040729132211",
                "modifieddate" : "20160115132957",
                "lganame" : "WALCHA",
                "councilname" : "WALCHA COUNCIL",
                "abscode" : 7850,
                "ltocode" : 6520,
                "vgcode" : 252,
                "wbcode" : null
            }
        },
```

Each LGA is represented like this. The JSON is valid, but when I try to convert using geo2topo I get this:-

```
> geo2topo LocalGovernmentArea=lgas_minified.json 
  {"type":"Topology","objects":{"LocalGovernmentArea":{}},"arcs":[]}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is my input not GeoJSON or am I using geo2json incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

Worked out the problem was that I had this in the JSON:-

"LocalGovernmentArea"

If you remove this element from the JSON and just flatten out the structure, everything works as expected.